# Can a git branch have a worktree?

Tags: git, config

So I have a git repository for a website I'm working on. The master repository has a worktree of /var/www/project/.
I want to create branches for myself and the other users on the server. I was wondering if I could set up a worktree on a branch to point to /home/username/public_html/ so they can work on their home directory and merge when needed.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`git clone /var/www/project ~/public_html`, then checkout the needed branch, and use `git pull` and `git push` as usual.